# bigARTM installation: Cmake Could NOT find Boost

Tags: python, git, macos, boost, cmake

I have an issue with `bigARTM` topic modelling library installing for `python 3.7` on `MacOs`:

Firstly, I install `Boost` with `pip install boost` and `Cmake` with same line
and then, as follows in documentation for `bigARTM`(https://bigartm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/linux.html#step-2-python-packages), do:

- `git clone --branch=stable https://github.com/bigartm/bigartm.git`
- `cd bigartm`
- `mkdir build && cd build`
- and ran `Cmake ..`

But get an error:

```
-- Build type: Release
CMake Error at /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2179 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:134 (find_package)
```

I understand that `Boost` lib is the problem, but I had installed earlier.

What has go wrong? How to fix it? What should I do to have `bigARTM` installed?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I install `Boost` with `pip install boost`" - No, `pip` may install only **python**-related things, but Boost generally is a **C++** library. The first step (at the end) tells to install Boost with `brew install boost`. Have you performed this action?

Comment: No, I haven't. I thought ```brew``` is the same as ```pip```.

Comment: So I have to uninstall ```Cmake``` and ```boost``` installed by ```pip``` and reinstall them with ```brew```?

Comment: As far as I know, `pip` provides `cmake` "compatible" with "normal" one (installed with distro-specific package manager). So it is up to you which `cmake` to use. As for `boost`,  you need to install it "normally". I don't know, whether uninstalling `boost` from `pip` is needed. If unsure then just follow the guide: as it doesn't specifies installation of `boost` from `pip`, then you shouldn't do that (and uninstall `boost` if you have it installed).

Comment: I really should've install ```boost``` using ```brew```. The error disappeared as I was able to install ```bigartm```. Thanks for explanation!